# Generating +/- 7v from EVM DC 1854A

Tags: voltage-regulator

I  am trying to generate +/- 7v from EVM DC 1854A, by default this evm can generate +/- 5v, by referring to datasheet of LT8471EFE using some formula we can calculate resistor values for generating different output voltages.

So i concluded that by changing R3 and R5 (got them from evm schematic) to 40k i can generate +/- 7v.

are those values enough or should in change some other components values too ?

Datasheet link of LT8471EFE : https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/8471fd.pdf

Data sheet of EVM : https://www.analog.com/media/en/dsp-documentation/evaluation-kit-manuals/DC1854AF.PDF

Formula used is: Vout = Vfb(1+Ra/Rb)

[image]

Thanks in Advance

Comment: No idea. Where is the datasheet link? What is the formula? What is the circuit you are using? If I told you I have a LM480turbo+ and there is a formula to give 100V out, would you be able to answer if I asked would changing R5 work? No, more information is needed

Comment: @MCG apologies for incomplete info. datasheet link of LT8471EFE :  https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/8471fd.pdf Data sheet of EVM : https://www.analog.com/media/en/dsp-documentation/evaluation-kit-manuals/DC1854AF.PDF Formula used is:    
Vout = Vfb(1+Ra/Rb)

Comment: Thanks for adding the information. Makes it easier to answer now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it looks like changing R3 and R5 (on the EVM) should enable you to change the output voltage.

The equation for Vout is: Vout = Vfb*(1+Ra/Rb).

In the case of this IC, Vfb is 0.789V for the positive Vout and -0.788V for the negative Vout (Datasheet page 14).

As the Vfb is almost the same, if you wanted an output of +7V and -7V, the resistors will match, thus we can work with just the positive output.

We know that Ra is 316k, Vout is 7 and Vfb is 0.789. If we re-arrange the formula for Rb, we get: Rb = Ra/((Vout/Vfb)-1) = 316000/((7/0.789)-1) = 40142.33.

This is pretty near 40k, so using 40k resistors, you will get pretty much ±7V out. If you wanted to spend a bit more, you can get 40.1k precision resistors to get closer to the 7V output voltage!

Comment: So no need of changing inductor or capacitor values right ? (I get that it is mentioned no where )

Comment: Nope, no need. Page 18 of the datasheet goes through output capacitors.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the data sheets for the part here:
https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/8471fd.pdf

On page 14, on the top right side, is the heading "Setting the Output Voltage (Primary Channels)". There is a description and the formula for selecting the proper resistor for the output voltage you want.

Use Application notes as much as you can to create what you need.

Typical of most circuits, there is a LOT of information to take into consideration when building this circuit.